# mktime causes overflow in SLES 15 SP3

Tags: c, linux, glibc, mktime

SLES 15 SP3 makes use of glibc 2.31 and our convert time code using mktime is failing with ulong overflow. Can anyone let us know if we are missing something here. Or do we have any other alternative system call that does the same?

```
main()
{
    time_t time_since_epoch = 0;
    struct tm gmTimetm; 
    gmTimetm.tm_year = 2022;
    gmTimetm.tm_mon = 02;
    gmTimetm.tm_mday = 24;
    gmTimetm.tm_hour = 11;
    gmTimetm.tm_min = 42;
    gmTimetm.tm_sec = 45;
    time_since_epoch = mktime(&gmTimetm);

    printf("%lu \n", time_since_epoch);
    return 0; 
}
```

OP:
18446744073709551615

Comment: gmTimetm.tm_year = 2022 - 1900;

Comment: Were you intentionally encoding the date 3922-03-24 or were you intending to encode 2022-02-24?  Even if you were intending to encode the future date, it looks like there was a problem.

Comment: Even adding gmTimetm.tm_year=2022 - 1900, the problem is still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tm_isdst needs to be set to -1. With that the issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

mktime() is failing. It is returning -1.

Comment: Yes, it is returning -1.

Comment: mktime() is not getting successful in converting the time. Try the newrst glibc - glibc 2.35 (https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). May be glibc 2.31 has a bug. You can also file a bug report with glibc.